# What directory is used for apps which installed via gnome-software?

Tags: gnome

Recently, I've installed telegram-desktop via gnome-software, but I cannot find telegram folder.

```
which telegram-desktop
which: no telegram-desktop in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl)
```

My question is where are apps stored after installing, via gnome-software? Can I manage this apps via terminal?

```
gnome-software --search=telegram-desktop
```

gives nothing.

Arch Linux

Comment: Have you checked the `gui` menu? It should be there. You can also run `updatedb` and then `locate telegram-desktop` as `root` to find the executable assuming `mlocate` is installed.

Comment: @Nasir Riley, I've found out with `mlocate`. Thanks a lot. The path is **/var/lib/flatpak/app**

Comment: Hi, great question. Please can you edit your question to date it, by showing your version of gnome-software? Maybe `pacman -Q gnome-software` will work, or at least the version number from "About".  "About" is an item in the app menu (not sure exact term?), and the app menu is in the top left of the screen just next to the gnome "Activities" menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is where are apps stored after installing, via gnome-software? Can I manage this apps via terminal?
>
> @Nasir Riley, I've found out with mlocate. Thanks a lot. The path is /var/lib/flatpak/app

On several different distributions, Telegram can be installed as a Flatpak.  In case you haven't found it yet, there is a `flatpak` command.

This does not apply to all apps installed by gnome-software. AFAIK there is no way to ask g-s what type of app you are installing.  Flatpak apps will show the "sandboxed" icon in g-s, but there can also be other types of sandboxed apps.  However in many cases you can tell by the Source field.  Apps from the main Flatpak Hub show a Source of `dl.flathub.org`.

Comment: Nice solution with **Flatpak**. Thank for answer. According to `man flatpak` there is the other elegant way to find telegram:
`flatpak list` - command show all installed apps via **Flatpak**
`flatpak info -l org.telegram.desktop/x86_64/stable` gives `/var/lib/flatpak/app/org.telegram.desktop/x86_64`